# Does fs.watch() keep hardware running?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-io

To track changes within my config file, I use:

```js
fs = require('fs');
fs.watch('./config.json',
  () => {
    try {
      this.reload();
    } catch (error) {
      try {
        setTimeout(() => this.reload(), 5000)
      } catch (error) {}
    }
  }
)
```

It is human readable/editable so I can (by hand) change the config while the Application is running.

The question is, does this keep the mechanical drive the config is stored on spinning?
Since I wont change the config that often, that would be a power waste and increase wear on the Drive.

I know about the problems of watch (Not perfect, sometimes registers multiple times...)
but it's generally good enough. The config is only changed manually every 60 days or sth and I can check whether the config reloaded or not.
If you have a better approach to reloading the config tho, let me know as well.

Comment: The watch happens at the OS/file system level, not at the hardware level. It's not keeping the read head hovering over the place where the file is; it's just subscribing to some OS/file system events so it gets notified when the file changes.

Comment: If you're confident that the config is only going to change every 60 days or so, why are you watching it every five seconds?

Comment: @Andy I dont. should the read fail, I just hope its nothing major and try again 5 seconds later in hopes it works then. If not the config wont get updated and I have to take a closer look anyways
I do seem to have missed the () behind the this.reload in the Timeout tho...